# How can I create .txt file in swift(MT940) format using node.js

Tags: node.js, mt940

How can I create .txt file in swift(MT940) format using node.js. 
Is there any npm module for that?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=swift(MT940)+format+using+node.js&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN714IN714&oq=swift(MT940)+format+using+node.js&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.450j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

node-mt940 npm module can be used. Link for that is below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mt940